# How can I find the size of this set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm sorry in advance for my bad english.
I got this question for homework and just can't solve it:

> There are 2 sets, $A$ and $B$ which are contained in $\mathbb{N}$ (the set of all natural numbers).
>
> - We know that the size of the cartesian product of $A$ and $B$ is $35$.
> - We also know that the size of $(A * B) \setminus (B * B)$ = 14.
> - We need to find the size of $A \cap B$.

Comment: **Hint**: the size of $A\times B$ is the product of the sizes of $A$ and $B$. Also, $35$ doesn't have that many divisors.

Comment: There are only four ordered pairs of naturals that multiply to $35$.  Have you just tried them all?

Comment: Is $A*B$ the Cartesian product $A \times B$?

Comment: You are fast! Yes, I know the options for the sizes of A and B are 1,35  5,7  7,5 and 35,1 But how do I continue? I also know that from the fact that the size of (A * B) \ (B * B) = 14 We can tell that there are 21 members of A * B that are also members of B * B and that eliminates the option of B of size 1,  but I can't see how this help know anything about the size of the intersection? or about the others options of sizes of A and B.

Comment: Yes mvw , A * B is the Cartesian product A×B

Answer (score 3):

$|A \times B| = 35$, so $|B| \in \{1, 5, 7, 35\}$ and $|A| = 35 / |B|$.

$|(A \times B) \setminus (B \times B)| = |(A \setminus B) \times B| = 14$, so $|B| \in \{1, 2, 7, 14\}$ and $|A \setminus B| = 14 / |B|$.

If $|B| = 1$, then $|A| = 35$ so $|A \setminus B|$ is 34 or 35, but $|A \setminus B| = 14$ if $|B| = 1$, so that's not possible.

So $|B| = 7$, $|A| = 5$ and $|A \setminus B| = 2$. It follows that $|A \cap B| = |A| - |A \setminus B| = 3$.

Comment: Thank you (I didnt know that it is allowed to transform (A x B) \ (B x B) into (A \ B) x B  )